# Celery task (.delay()) causes Django to freeze if I'm using Gunicorn or uWsgi

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, redis, celery, gunicorn

If I'm using celery with Django (by calling .delay()) while using Gunicorn or uWsgi it causes it to freeze and eventually timeout. I'm guessing it gets stuck trying to send task to broker. This is happening on both developer server and production server, where both are running Ubuntu 20.04.

Using built in developer server using
python3 manage.py runserver
works without any issues.

And removing the .delay() also makes it work automatically.

**Example task:**

```
@shared_task
def SayHello():
    print('Hello!')
```

**Celery config in settings.py:**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:password@ip:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://:password@ip:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENt = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER ='json'
```

**init**.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**celery.py (in project folder with settings.py):**

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'djangoProject.settings')

app = Celery('djangoProject')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.config_from_object(__name__)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

Answer (score 0):

After a day of pulling my hair out, I think I found it.

I removed the following lines from my celery.py file:

```
celery = Celery(__name__)
celery.config_from_object(__name__)
```